# javascript table alignment

Tags: javascript, html

[image: web page picture]

I'm trying to align the tables' titles with the items form another page using a js loop, tried padding, spacing etc.. nothing worked!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let products = ['bread', 'sweets', 'coffee'];

  $('#prepurchased').html('<table class ="thead"id="items" ><tr><th>Item</th><th> </th><th>Price</th><th>quantity</th></tr>');

  products.forEach(function(i) {
    let p = sessionStorage.getItem(i);

    if (p !== null) {
      p = JSON.parse(p);

      $('#prepurchased').append('<table id="items" class="cart" align="center"><tr><td>' + i + '</td>' + '<td>$' + p.price + '</td>' + '<td>' + p.quantity + '</td></tr>');

      $('#purchase').css('display', 'block');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js" integrity="sha512-AA1Bzp5Q0K1KanKKmvN/4d3IRKVlv9PYgwFPvm32nPO6QS8yH1HO7LbgB1pgiOxPtfeg5zEn2ba64MUcqJx6CA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. Use the stack snippets feature of the question editor. Don't muddy the water with multiple versions of the same code, some commented out. Do include the HTML needed to run it.

Comment: I tried to make a snippet of your code, but it's erroring. Please see if you can fix it so we can debug. You may have to swap out the session storage data for a local variable.

Comment: why do you use multiple tables instead of one with multiple rows (that would fix your issue). Or better why do you avoid using tables at all and start using divs for this?

Comment: A table is the correct structure for this type of data (contrary to my initial comment). Conversion to divs shouldn't be a knee-jerk response. However, a _single_ table seems appropriate, as you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your data should be in the same `<table>`. That's what tables are for. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Also:

- It seems you wanted to separate `<thead>` and `<tbody>`
- I removed an empty `<th>` that was confusing
- You made your "purchase" button visible at each data row, which doesn't seem useful
- `if (p !== null)` doesn't prevent rendering the JSON when `p` is `undefined`. Just write `if (p)` instead
- `$(document).ready(...)` is longer to write. You may use the shorthand `$(...)`
- *I had to fake sessionStorage for the snippet to run live.*

```js
$(_e => {
  const products = ['bread', 'sweets', 'coffee'];

  $('#prepurchased').html('<table class="cart" id="items"><thead><tr><th>Item</th><th>Price</th><th>quantity</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>');

  products.forEach(i => {
    //let p = sessionStorage.getItem(i);  //TODO: restore this
    let p = fakeStorage[i];               //TODO: remove this

    if (p) {
      p = JSON.parse(p);

      $('#prepurchased .cart tbody').append('<tr><td>' + i + '</td>' + '<td>$' + p.price + '</td>' + '<td>' + p.quantity + '</td></tr>');
    }
  });

  if (products.length)
    $('#purchase').css('display', 'block');
});

//TODO: remove, for testing only (sessionStorage rises error with cross-domain js)
fakeStorage = {
  'bread': '{"price": 21.2, "quantity": 25}',
  'coffee': '{"price": 34.55, "quantity": 32}',
  /*'sweets': '{"price": 6.12, "quantity": 1}',*/
};
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.cart {
  text-align: center;
}

.cart th {
  width: 15em;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js" integrity="sha512-AA1Bzp5Q0K1KanKKmvN/4d3IRKVlv9PYgwFPvm32nPO6QS8yH1HO7LbgB1pgiOxPtfeg5zEn2ba64MUcqJx6CA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="prepurchased"></div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button id="purchase" style="display: none">Purchase</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much! I'm actually new to js and this was my first project which explains why I've done all those mistakes xD

Comment: We've all been there. Haven't we?